# Custom classes data tooltips in Matlab editor

Tags: matlab, undocumented-behavior

Does any one would know a way of overriding the data tooltip that is shown when hovering over a variable when we are in the Matlab editor ? I have a custom class that is relatively simple and its content could be shown easily in the tool tip, but Matlab insists on saying it is a 1x1 CustomClass, which is nice and all, but it would be more useful if we could make it to show the content of the object in a nice way. Right now, I have to type the name of the variable in the cmd window e.g. when debugging instead of a short hover on the variable name. Nitpicky, but I'd find it interesting ^^

I've tried to dig a bit using undocumented leads on data tooltips, e.g. http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/accessing-the-matlab-editor/
http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/spicing-up-matlab-uicontrol-tooltips/

But I don't have the final answer, anyone has any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltip seems to get its string by using the `disp` method. Override `disp` on your class. In the method body, construct your desired string however you want and then call `disp` on it. In R2012a at least this works for the debugger tooltip.

Note that you'll need to do a `clear classes` after editing the class to get MATLAB to recognize the overridden `disp`.